# How to change class' prototype at runtime within this class (with ES6 classes)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have the following class 'X' and I want to add some stuff to its `prototype` dynamically, like this (this **works**):

```js
    class X{
        someUnrelatedFunction(){}; 
    }
    
    //adding some stuff at runtime, in real situation, the ['a','b','c'] aren't "known" in advance like here.

    ['a','b','c'].forEach(elem => {
     X.prototype[elem] = () =>{
           console.log('called with : ' + elem);
      };
    })

    //tests:

    x = new X();
    x.c();//works, outputs 'called with : c';
```

**But** in the `class` declaration itself. I would like to do it, to make things a bit more readable, i.e. I would like the 'prototype' initialization to belong to the class itself.

Right now I'm doing this in a 'constructor', like here:

```js
class X{
 constructor(){
   //we don't want to do that again:
   if(typeof X.prototype.inited === 'undefined'){
     X.prototype.inited = true;
     console.log('-constructor: initing prototype');
      ['a','b','c'].forEach(elem => {
        X.prototype[elem] = () =>{
          console.log('called with : ' + elem);
        };
      })      
   }else{
     console.log('-constructor: no need to re-init prototype');
    } 
  }
}


x1 = new X();
x1.a();

x2 = new X();
x2.b();
```

fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/nypL29f3/4/

But this seems tricky for me, plus inside the class I'm actually referencing it kinda "outside", i.e. I'm using "X". If I ever changed the class name, I will also need to change that part of code.

So the question is - how to do that in a more readable and right way?

FWIW, The "real" case scenario is that I'm playing with ES6 by creating useless scripts like this one:

https://jsfiddle.net/kpion/mqyrewnx/9/

Here my doubts were about line #78 //this was my question - that it seems I need to do it outside the class YaLog.

**Edit**: just BTW - if you came here with a similar question - all the below answers answer the question in a way, and all are worth reading. Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Class syntax is essentially a handy way to declaratively define a prototype object. Since you specifically want to do it programmatically, doing that outside the class declaration seems very reasonable to me.

Comment: There is no 'right' way to do this. This approach is just wrong by design. if you have a specific case, there's a chance that you have XY problem. Please, update the question with relevant details, this way a proper alternative could be suggested. Posting real code instead of ABC abstractions may help to understand the problem, too.

Comment: @loganfsmyth - thanks!

Comment: @estus - Thanks as well. I edited my code to add the specific case, it's here, on line #78: https://jsfiddle.net/mqyrewnx/8/

Comment: I see. Yes, this is a common case, it's always handled from outside the class. Decorators are often used for that, I added the answer for completeness. The approach is similar to what's suggested in another answer but it's more conventional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use inheritance. Create new class `Y` and add it methods from your array. Then you can extend original class (or any other) with `Y`:

```
class Y {}
const methods = ['a', 'b', 'c']
methods.forEach(elem => {
  Y.prototype[elem] = () => {
    console.log('called with : ' + elem)
  }
})

class X extends Y {
  someUnrelatedFunction() {}
}

const x1 = new X();
x1.a();
```

I am not sure what your use case is, but you can create a helper function which extends your original class. For example this could also work:

```
function extendWithMethods(methodNames, generalHandler) {
  class Y {}
  methodNames.forEach(elem => {
    Y.prototype[elem] = () => generalHandler(elem)
  })
  return Y
}

class X extends extendWithMethods(['a', 'b', 'c'], methodName => {
  console.log('called with : ' + methodName)
}) {
  someUnrelatedFunction() {}
}

const x1 = new X()
x1.a()
```

Comment: Thanks, but the whole point was to do all the things, related to any given  class, **inside** this class. I rephrased my question, and emphasized "but" :) - "**But** in the class declaration itself." to make it more clear :)

Comment: Wooow, didn't know we can do that, i.e. extend a... function returning a class :) Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

This sort of class prototype modifications is never performed from inside a constructor - primarily because class constructor is responsible for managing current class instance, not all class instances. A constructor is supposed to declare new methods ('log','info', etc) on `this` class instance, this is less efficient than declaring methods on class `prototype` and may be desirable or not for further class inheritance.

This is what decorators are intended for. They provide a convenient syntax for extension or modification class constructor and prototype.

A decorator can modify existing class `prototype`:

```
function withLogger(Class) {
  ['log','info','error','warn','group','groupEnd'].forEach(func => {
    Class.prototype[func] = function() {
      return this.callConsoleMethod(func, ...arguments);
    };
  });

  return Class;
}
```

Or return a new class that extends existing class in non-destructive way, this allows to refer original members with `super` when shadowing them in wrapper class.

Decorators have neat syntax in ECMAScript Next/TypeScript:

```
@withLogger
class YaLog {
  ...
}
```

Since a decorator is basically a helper function, it can be applied directly in ES6 in a bit less expressive manner:

```
const YaLog = withLogger(class YaLog {
  ...
});
```

Comment: Thank you! This is quite similar¹ to the answer I already accepted, so I'll leave acceptance as it is now. But yeah, this way is seems cooler if I ever wanted to 'decorate' with more that one decorator. So TIL, thank you! -- ¹ "similar" as in  - we have the prototype building process not bleeding into current scope - whichever it is. Which is basically what I didn't like about my solution. That... there was a code executing just like that, out of nowhere :) Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome. Notice that in accepted answer the inheritance is reverse, i.e. child class can shadow decorated methods, intentionally or not.

Comment: @konrados You really should use a decorator that modifies exactly your class, not create an artificial inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: @Bergi Thanks, will do it:)

Answer (score 2):

> I would like the 'prototype' initialization to belong to the class itself.

That is not possible. A class body can only contain method definitions, not arbitrary code.

If the number of methods was known and only their names are dynamic, you could use computed property names, but this doesn't seem to be the case in your example.

Since you are looking for a more readable way, just put the class and all assignments of static values or dynamically created methods in a separate module. (This might be an ES6 module, an IIFE module, or a simple block scope for visual separation).

> Right now I'm doing this in the `constructor`

Don't. This is inefficient, error-prone and horribly unreadable.

Answer (score 0):

This definitely works, it is not that readable but you don't need to specify the class name to reach its prototype:

```
class X {
  constructor() {
    const myPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);

    // Note that Object.getOwnPropertyNames() includes the constructor method:
    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myPrototype).length <= 1) {
      console.log('constructor: initing prototype');
      ['a', 'b', 'c'].forEach((elem) => {
        myPrototype[elem] = () => {
          console.log('called with : ' + elem);
        };
      });
    } else {
      console.log('constructor: no need to re-init prototype');
    }
  }
}
```

For me, more interesting than iterating an array like `['a', 'b', 'c']` is that you can also iterate some arbitrary class methods:

```
class X {
  constructor(someObject) {
    const myPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
    const someClassPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(someObject);

    if (Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myPrototype).length <= 1) {
      const classMethodNames = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(someClassPrototype);
      classMethodNames.forEach((method) => {
        myPrototype[method] = someClassPrototype[method];
      });
    } 
  }
}
```

Or simpler but not less hazardous:

```
class X {
  constructor(someObject) {
    let myPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);

    Object.setPrototypeOf(myPrototype, someObject);
  }
}
```

**Note that all this assumes you are changing prototypes of simple "shallow" classes because I am sure there are a bunch of caveats here.**

Comment: Wow, thanks! I had to remind myself what I was asking about :)